# Prevent collapse in Firefox Devtools' Storage tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Suppose I'm using the Firefox Devtools, the "Storage" tab is active, the "Cookies" tab is expanded, and and localhost is selected. Then I can see all the cookies.

When a page navigation or refresh occurs, the tree on the left ("Cache Storage", "Cookies", etc.) is collapsed. So once again I must expand "Cookies", select localhost, etc.

This makes development and debugging very slow and annoying.

Is there a way to prevent that collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and unfortunate answer is no. I've filed a [feature request for that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1388271) several years ago, though as of Firefox 123.0 this is not implemented yet.